# How do I show label value on Grafana dashboard?

Tags: prometheus, grafana-loki

I am using Loki (Promtail) to collect log. The information I need is grouped by every three lines (their timestamp are the same).

log example:
1/1/2021 10:01:23 AM Memory
1/1/2021 10:01:23 AM 2300 Mb
1/1/2021 10:01:23 AM 23%
1/1/2021 10:01:13 AM Memory
1/1/2021 10:01:13 AM 2310 Mb
...

I can already capture the values for these labels: timestamp, metric, available_memory_mb, and available_memory_percent - I can get timestamp and metric from the first line, get timestamp and available_memory_mb from the second line, and get timestamp and available_memory_percent from the third line.

Is there a way for me to put metric, available_memory_mb, and available_memory_percent with the same timestamp (as legend) on a Grafana dashboard? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Loki cannot correlate multiple lines. (There is a [feature](https://github.com/grafana/loki/issues/74) announced for Loki 2.2 but that is not yet released).

What you could do (if you have the chance to change how the log file is written) is put all the information in one line like

```
1/1/2021 10:01:23 AM Memory 2300 Mb 23%
```